# How to force the order of a `terms` query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a simple `terms` query with a list of IDs defined. My goal is to get results back in the same order as it was defined in the input array. How to achieve that?

```
{
    query: {
        terms: {
            _id: ["12", "34", "6", "22"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check below my answer and marked as solution and upvote if it really helps you.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Script based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/sort-search-results.html#script-based-sorting) for same. you can provide sort order and based on it, script will order your response.

```json
POST index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "id": ["12", "34", "6", "22"]
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "inline": "params.sortOrder.indexOf(doc['id'].value)",
        "params": {
          "sortOrder": ["12", "34", "6", "22"]
        }
      },
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```